# Jsoup and parser's Tidy-fication

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

Reading Jsoup's documentation I didn't understand if Jsoup applies Tidy before parsing a html file. 
In this case, it's possible to disable tidy?

Did you know other Java HTML5 parsers without tidy-fication of the page source?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by tidyfication?

Comment: With "Tidyfication" i mean "cleaning up malformed and faulty HTML" (as JTidy, Html_Tidy and a lot of other "Something-Tidy" libreries do). I need a Java Html5 parser who parses messy html....

Comment: IDK if there's any. Have you tried using the native Java API? It will get you all the data, and with its own indentation. I'll post the answer with a way to do that

Comment: I used Java API. Thanks a lot! May I use it also for css parsing?

Comment: Well, I have not tried it yet. But I guess, you could search in the code for the css file path, and get its content using the native API as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This Oracle article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) might solve your problem. It's native API, and it does what you want. Simple and effective